# visual studio code doesn't give me space between curly brackets in CSS when i hit enter

Tags: css, curly-braces

i want vc code to create space when i do { + enter key

VS Code does this

```
h1 {
|}
```

i want VS Code to do this

```
h1 {
 |
}
```

Comment: Are you editing a .css file? It works fine for me

Comment: Yes, i'm editing a .css file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by deleting all JSON settings

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer

Comment: i will remember it for the future, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was

```
"editor.language.brackets": [],
```

in vscode settings.json

Comment: More information about why this answer works would improve the quality of this answer.